# Posting WCF Data

Tags: c#, wcf

I am quite new to WCF and I am having some trouble trying to POST data from a class to the service response.

```
public class PingService : ItemData
{

    public GetUrl GetUrlData(string GET_XML)
    {


        GetUrl data = new GetUrl(GetUrl.GET_XML_DATA);


        //Generates string xml_final


        //What I want to do
        return xml_final

        //My only option
        return data ;

    }}
```

My question is that how would I return the xml_final string? It would give me an error saying that "It cannot convert string to WcfService2.GetUrl" which, I assume, means that I cannot simply put in a string for a return.

Below are my Service and Data Contracts.

```
[ServiceContract]
[XmlSerializerFormat]
public interface ItemData
{
    //[OperationContract]
    //string GetItemData(GetUrl data);

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
        UriTemplate = "GetUrl/{GET_XML}")]

    //XML TAGS for Service
    GetUrl GetUrlData(string GET_XML)
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
       UriTemplate = "GetUrl")]
    Stream TestPost(Stream stream);

}

[DataContract]
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "GetUrl")]
public class GetUrl
{
     [XmlAttribute("uri")]
    public static string GET_XML_DATA { get; set; }

    public string GET_XML { get; set; }


    public GetUrl() { }

    public GetUrl(string xml)
    {
        this.GET_XML = xml;
    }
}
```

Comment: why do you want to return xml instead of object of type GetUrl?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`return new GetUrl(xml_final);` instead of `return xml_final` which gives you the error.